# How to handle the missing values' issue of newly listed stocks?

Tags: econometrics, finance, financial-economics, time-series

I am trying to test some asset pricing models on 10 portfolios for the period of 2010-2020. The problem is that three of these portfolios included stocks that are newly listed in 2017 and 2018, so I only have three years of historical data for these stocks. Can anyone help how to solve this problem? I don't want to exclude these stocks; does imputation makes sense for such a long period?

Comment: The same on Cross Validated: [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/522402).

Answer (score 1):

I have found some posts to help answer your question.   In a post on ResearchGate.net,
https://www.researchgate.net/post/How-to-deal-with-missing-value-in-a-time-series-stock-market-data

One of the responses that I think has the best answer for your is to carry forward the previous data . However,  as the person stated,  there is a problem with that method.    “*--- if you are developing a trading system, for example, and assume that prices are "tradable", then your analysis will be flawed since you can't trade at a "carried forward price." My solution to this problem is this: create a 'locf' price and as a separate variable, a "tradable price", which when data is missing, is (approximately) the next price you could have realized. “*

However,  Mazin A. M. Al Janabi  posted a link on that page which has a better answer for you.  https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Mazin-Al-Janabi/post/How-to-deal-with-missing-value-in-a-time-series-stock-market-data/attachment/5b73a9633843b0024405fcb1/AS%3A659744100450305%401534306659149/download/Dealing+with+the+Problem+of+Missing+Data-+A+short+Note.pdf
He states that you either not include the missing data or you can calculate the price from a geometric mean of the previous and other price data. **However using average prices will underestimate the volatility of the stock price data.**

Here is another response to a similar question on Stackexchange: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/41171/how-to-deal-with-missing-value-in-a-time-series-stock-market-data

I have also posted a similar answer on missing data but not missing stock price data [How do I fill gaps in my data?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/27591/how-do-i-fill-gaps-in-my-data/27594#27594)

Either case I think it is VERY important that you document that you have missing data, report which observations are missing, and what method you used to remedy it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I will go through all your reading suggestions. Much appreciated.

Comment: Awesome.  Good luck with your project.